# Count elements of each sublist

Tags: haskell

So I was strugging with this function doing calculation of length of each sublist. It takes a list containing sublists and return a new list with each element specifies the size of each sublist.

Something like:

```
*Main> count [[], ["this", "is"], ["a", "test", "!!!"]]
```

should return

```
[0,2,3]
```

Here is what I have so far, but it only prints the total size of every sublist of the entire list which is

```
[5]
```

Code:

```
count :: [[a]] -> [Int]
count [] = []
count (x:xs) =  [1 + myLength (x:xs)]
```

Btw myLength is a trivial function I wrote to calculate the size.

Answer (score 4):

There are Prelude defined `length` and `map`. So your count can be defined as simple as:

```
count = map length
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that your input list is list of list, so you have to do this:

```
count :: [[a]] -> [Int]
count [] = []
count (x:xs) =  (myLength x):(count xs)
```

You need to calculate the length using `myLength` function and for each element of the list and build it up using `:` function. `xs` will be the rest of the list, which you have to pass it to `count` again to compute it.

Answer (score 0):

**Eugene Sh** offered the best (simplest) answer above: just use `map length` on your input.

But it sounds like this problem is homework, where the intent is to demonstrate basic understanding of recursion. So really we shouldn't be helping you :) But I will try to explain in a way that gives more than merely the answer.

With any recursive definition, you must first define your base cases. Since you are dealing with *lists of lists*, your simplest case is a list containing **no sublists** - its patterns looks like `[]`.

You also have to define a *recursive case* (sometimes also called an *inductive case*), in which the right-hand side of the equation will contain a reference to the very function being defined.

So, your two necessary definitions for a sublists length function called `len`:

```
len (xs:xss) = length xs : len xss
len _        = []
```

Our first line defines the recursive case; notice its right-hand side contains a reference to the function we are defining (`len`, in this example). We use the popular Haskell conventions of `xs` for a list of arbitrary content type, and `xss` for a list of lists. The overall pattern, `(xs:xss)` matches any input with a list (`xs`) followed by any number of further lists (`xss`) - note, this could mean **zero** further lists! In that case, the pattern would concretely be `xs:[]`.

For the second line, we did not bother to give an explicit pattern - we used the *wildcard pattern* `_`. This communicates to Haskell (and other programmers) the fact that we want `[]` to be returned for **any** input other than the one matched by the line above. Thus, when our recursion finally reaches the end of the list, it encounters a pattern like `[]` - a single list, not followed by any other lists. This is our *base case*, where we define the final output which ends the recursion.